# UILabel is not updating objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have three view controllers A,B,C. In view controller B, i make a service call and update a UILabel based on the response of that  service. Requirement if to only show that label in view controller B when we navigate from view controller A. And hide it if we navigate from view controller C.

So i have BOOL property in view controller B, called "loadService". I set it to true if we navigate from view controller A in prepareForSegue method. like below -

```
 if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:"VCA"])
    {
        ViewControllerA *vca = segue.destinationViewController;
        vca.loadService = true;
    }
```

And in View controller B, I have code like below -

```
if (loadService) {

    [self.custProfileMgr getCustomerProfile:^(NSDictionary *custDict) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (custDict != nil) {
                        self.topView.lblWelcome.text =  val returned from service;

            }
        });
    } failureBlock:^(NSDictionary *failDict) {

    }];
        loadService = false;
    }else{
        self.topView.lblWelcome.text = @"";
        self.topView.lblWelcome.hidden = true;

    }
```

So i am able to assign value from the service return to the label when we navigate from VC A to VC B. And its working fine. But I am not able to hide it when we navigate from VC C to VC B. I have tried debugging the app and I see when we navigate from VC C to VC B, the curser is going to else condition loadService is false and it is hiding the text also, but somehow the screen it does not update and the label is still there. I am not not sure what is wrong here. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide the code you've got in `prepareForSegue` for VC C?

Comment: try `self.topView.lblWelcome layoutIfNeeded`

Comment: @brandonscript I don't have prepareForSegue in VC C, I am setting up loadService to false in VC B itself.And i have tested the curser does go to else condition when we navigate from VC C.

Comment: @New16 Can you elaborate? I dinn understand properly

Comment: try to change alpha of the label  like this "self.theLabel.alpha = 1;"

Comment: If you're not using `prepareForSegue` in VC C, that's probably the problem. Your other option is to default it to `hidden`, and set it to visible in VC A's `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: after setting the hidden = true, try `[self.topView.lblWelcome layoutIfNeeded]` this will induce the UI engine to redraw the label. At this point of time it should hide the label.

Comment: Just tried all the suggestions ... and nope nothing is working @brandonscript I don't thing so prepareForSegue in VC C is problem here, because goes to else condition only where i am setting the label to hidden but its not hiding somehow on screen

Comment: In what method in VCB are you calling `if (loadService) {}`? If it's too early in the VC initialisation cycle self.topView could be nil. The best place to do this would be in viewWillAppear.